# TikZ - Placing several numbers in one cell of a Sudoku grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, sudoku

I've put at the end of this post one code coming from [this page](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/sudoku/) which is a pretty easy way to display Sudoku grid.

I would like to have help so as to add the possibility to indicate several entries in one cell like in the following screenshot ? This is to indicate how to solve the sudoku without giving the answer.

[image]

**My question is about one TiKz way to produce at least the first preceding case with nine possibilities.**

### Code, from TeXample.net, that displays a Sudoku grid

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \newcounter{row}
    \newcounter{col}

    \newcommand\setrow[9]{
        \setcounter{col}{1}
        \foreach \n in {#1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #8, #9} {
            \edef\x{\value{col} - 0.5}
            \edef\y{9.5 - \value{row}}
            \node[anchor=center] at (\x, \y) {\n};
            \stepcounter{col}
        }
        \stepcounter{row}
    }


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
  \begin{scope}
    \draw (0, 0) grid (9, 9);
    \draw[very thick, scale=3] (0, 0) grid (3, 3);

    \setcounter{row}{1}
    \setrow { }{2}{ }  {5}{ }{1}  { }{9}{ }
    \setrow {8}{ }{ }  {2}{ }{3}  { }{ }{6}
    \setrow { }{3}{ }  { }{6}{ }  { }{7}{ }

    \setrow { }{ }{1}  { }{ }{ }  {6}{ }{ }
    \setrow {5}{4}{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{1}{9}
    \setrow { }{ }{2}  { }{ }{ }  {7}{ }{ }

    \setrow { }{9}{ }  { }{3}{ }  { }{8}{ }
    \setrow {2}{ }{ }  {8}{ }{4}  { }{ }{7}
    \setrow { }{1}{ }  {9}{ }{7}  { }{6}{ }

    \node[anchor=center] at (4.5, -0.5) {Unsolved Sudoku};
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[xshift=12cm]
    \draw (0, 0) grid (9, 9);
    \draw[very thick, scale=3] (0, 0) grid (3, 3);

    \setcounter{row}{1}
    \setrow { }{2}{ }  {5}{ }{1}  { }{9}{ }
    \setrow {8}{ }{ }  {2}{ }{3}  { }{ }{6}
    \setrow { }{3}{ }  { }{6}{ }  { }{7}{ }

    \setrow { }{ }{1}  { }{ }{ }  {6}{ }{ }
    \setrow {5}{4}{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{1}{9}
    \setrow { }{ }{2}  { }{ }{ }  {7}{ }{ }

    \setrow { }{9}{ }  { }{3}{ }  { }{8}{ }
    \setrow {2}{ }{ }  {8}{ }{4}  { }{ }{7}
    \setrow { }{1}{ }  {9}{ }{7}  { }{6}{ }

    \node[anchor=center] at (4.5, -0.5) {Solved Sudoku};

    \begin{scope}[blue, font=\sffamily]
      \setcounter{row}{1}
      \setrow {4}{ }{6}  { }{7}{ }  {3}{ }{8}
      \setrow { }{5}{7}  { }{9}{ }  {1}{4}{ }
      \setrow {1}{ }{9}  {4}{ }{8}  {2}{ }{5}

      \setrow {9}{7}{ }  {3}{8}{5}  { }{2}{4}
      \setrow { }{ }{3}  {7}{2}{6}  {8}{ }{ }
      \setrow {6}{8}{ }  {1}{4}{9}  { }{5}{3}

      \setrow {7}{ }{4}  {6}{ }{2}  {5}{ }{1}
      \setrow { }{6}{5}  { }{1}{ }  {9}{3}{ }
      \setrow {3}{ }{8}  { }{5}{ }  {4}{ }{2}
    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This sudoku uses 1cm x 1cm squares. If you make them bigger, you can use `\begin{tabular}{ccc}1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9\end{tabular}` inside any position.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I introduced some new commands to help explaining sudokus:

**UPDATE**: Highlights are put in background as suggested by Claudio Fiandrino. Also a new `\highligthrectangle` was added to highlight arbitrary rectangular sections, such as quadrants. Note how several highligths can overlap.

```
    % Highlight some cells
    \highlightcell{2}{8}
    \highlightrow{8}
    \highlighcolumn{5}
    \highlightrectangle{4}{1}{6}{3}

    % Other marks
    \circlecell{5}{2}
    \crosscell{8}{1}

    % Hints
    \hintcell{5}{5}{2,7,8}
    \hintcell{1}{1}{3,4,6,7}
```

Resulting in:

[image: Hinted sudoku]

The code is as follows.

```
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
% Some customizable styles
\tikzset {
  highlight/.style = {yellow, opacity=0.3},
  digit/.style = { minimum height = 5mm, minimum width=5mm, anchor=center },
  circle/.style = {draw=green!80!black, dotted, very thick},
  cross/.style = {red, opacity=.5, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm, very thick, line cap=round},
  hint/.style={blue, font=\sf, minimum width=3mm, minimum height=3mm}
}

% Original code-----------------------------------------------------------
% Modified the \node to give a unique name to each one, which is the
% row number, a dash and the column number. E.g: 1-1, 4-5, etc.
\newcounter{row}
\newcounter{col}

\newcommand\setrow[9]{
    \setcounter{col}{1}
    \foreach \n in {#1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #8, #9} {
        \edef\x{\value{col} - 0.5}
        \edef\y{9.5 - \value{row}}
        \node[digit,name={\arabic{row}-\arabic{col}}] at (\x, \y) {\n};
        \stepcounter{col}
    }
    \stepcounter{row}
}

% New code -------------------------------------------------------------
\def\highlightcell#1#2{
\fill[highlight] (#1-#2.north west) rectangle (#1-#2.south east);
}

\def\circlecell#1#2{
\draw[circle] (#1-#2) circle(4mm);
}

\def\crosscell#1#2{
\draw[cross] (#1-#2.north west) -- (#1-#2.south east);
\draw[cross] (#1-#2.north east) -- (#1-#2.south west);
}

\def\highlightrow#1{
\fill[highlight] (#1-1.north west) rectangle (#1-9.south east);
}

\def\highlighcolumn#1{
\fill[highlight] (1-#1.north west) rectangle (9-#1.south east);
}

\def\hintcell#1#2#3{
\node at (#1-#2) {\hintbox{#3}};
}

\def\highlightrectangle#1#2#3#4{
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\fill[highlight] (#1-#2.north west) rectangle (#3-#4.south east);
\end{pgfonlayer}
}

% UGLY code. Do not read :-)
\def\hintbox#1{
\resizebox{4.5mm}{4.5mm}{%
\tikz[scale=0.3]{%
  \def\auxc{0}
  \foreach \m in {1,...,9} {
    \pgfmathparse{mod(\auxc,3)}
    \xdef\x{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{-floor(\auxc/3)}
    \xdef\y{\pgfmathresult}
    \xdef\hintprinted{0}
    \foreach \n in {#1} {
      \ifnum\n=\m
       \node[hint] at (\x,\y) {\n};
       \xdef\hintprinted{1}
      \fi
     }
   \ifnum\hintprinted=0
      \node[hint, opacity=0.1] at (\x,\y) {\m};
   \fi
   \pgfmathparse{\auxc+1} 
   \xdef\auxc{\pgfmathresult}   }
  }%
 }
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
  \begin{scope}
    \draw (0, 0) grid (9, 9);
    \draw[very thick, scale=3] (0, 0) grid (3, 3);

    \setcounter{row}{1}
    \setrow { }{2}{ }  {5}{ }{1}  { }{9}{ }
    \setrow {8}{ }{ }  {2}{ }{3}  { }{ }{6}
    \setrow { }{3}{ }  { }{6}{ }  { }{7}{ }

    \setrow { }{ }{1}  { }{ }{ }  {6}{ }{ }
    \setrow {5}{4}{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{1}{9}
    \setrow { }{ }{2}  { }{ }{ }  {7}{ }{ }

    \setrow { }{9}{ }  { }{3}{ }  { }{8}{ }
    \setrow {2}{ }{ }  {8}{ }{4}  { }{ }{7}
    \setrow { }{1}{ }  {9}{ }{7}  { }{6}{ }

    \node[anchor=center] at (4.5, -0.5) {Unsolved Sudoku};

    % Highlight some cells
    \highlightcell{2}{8}
    \highlightrow{8}
    \highlighcolumn{5}
    \highlightrectangle{4}{1}{6}{3}

    % Other marks
    \circlecell{5}{2}
    \crosscell{8}{1}

    % Hints
    \hintcell{5}{5}{2,7,8}
    \hintcell{1}{1}{3,4,6,7}
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Nice, +1. What about putting the `highlightedcell` in `background`?

Comment: Now implement a sudoku solver and animate it!

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Yes! It is easy in this case because all is done in the same `tikzpicture`, so no `tikzmark` hackery is required. Thanks for the suggestion! (answer updated)

Comment: @AndrewStacey I'll leave that for you :-)

Comment: @AndrewStacey [iTeX therefore iSolve? :)](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/i-tex-therefore-ipad-reloaded/?cb=1)

Comment: @JLDiaz : great, pretty and usefull solution. I propose to rather use `\highlightcell{2}{8}`, `\highlightrow{8}`, `\highlighcolumn{5}` and `\highlightrectangle{4}{1}{6}{3}` for a btter view of the functionnalities.

Comment: @AndrewStacey : hoping that you are joking... :-)

Comment: @projetmbc Ok, good idea. This way it can be seen that other marks like circles and crosses can be added to highlighted cells.