# How to merge cells borders (drawing walls in a grid)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fit, cell

I want a draw a wall on a gridcell. Currently I have [this](https://www.sharelatex.com/read/tqybkhvphvqy):
[image]

```
    %based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91429/69931 
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[margin=0cm,nohead]{geometry} 
    \usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview} 
    \PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

    \usetikzlibrary{fit}
% Some customizable styles
    \tikzset {
        highlight/.style = {yellow, opacity=0.3},
        digit/.style = {minimum height = 5mm, minimum width=5mm, anchor=center },
        circle/.style = {draw=green!80!black, dotted, very thick},
        circle number/.style = {draw=#1,very thick},
        cross/.style = {red, opacity=.5, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm, very thick, line cap=round},
        hint/.style={blue, font=\sf, minimum width=3mm, minimum height=3mm}
    }

    \newcounter{hi}
    \setcounter{hi}{5}

    \newcounter{row}
    \newcounter{col}

    \newcommand\setrow[9]{
        \setcounter{col}{1}
        \foreach \n in {#1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #8, #9} {
            \edef\x{\value{col} - 0.5}
            \edef\y{\value{hi} + 0.5 - \value{row}}
            \node[digit,name={\arabic{row}-\arabic{col}}] at (\x, \y) {\n};
            \stepcounter{col}
        }
        \stepcounter{row}
    }

    \def\wallcells#1{
        \node[draw=black,thick, fill=black!50, opacity=0.5, fit=#1,inner sep=0pt] {};
    }

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
        \begin{scope}
            \draw (0, 0) grid (9, \value{hi});
            \setcounter{row}{1}
            \setrow {}{}{}  {}{}{}  {}{}{}
            \setrow {}{}{}  {}{}{}  {}{}{}
            \setrow {}{}{}  {}{}{}  {}{}{}

            \setrow {}{}{}  {}{}{}  {}{}{}
            \setrow {}{}{}  {}{}{}  {}{}{}
        \end{scope}

    \wallcells{(1-3) (1-6)}
    \wallcells{(1-5) (3-5)}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Yet what I want is a seamless walls merge (same transparant grey, single border only surrounding wall cels) alike:
[image: photoshoped image]

Comment: You can either draw them all in one color (no transparency) or take a look at transparency groups in the pgf manual, https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any automatic solution to solve this superposition problem. But here you have a manual solution.

The grid is drawn with a `matrix of empty nodes`. The nodes that you want to fill are declared inside a `.list` with a particular `style`. Finally the border is manually drawn using perpendicular segments around filled matrix nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mygrid/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        nodes={draw, minimum size=1cm},
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth},
    myset/.style args= {(#1,#2)}{%
        row #1 column #2/.style={nodes={fill=red!30, opacity=.5}}}
        ]

\matrix (A) [mygrid, myset/.list={(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,5),(3,5)}]{
    &&&&&&&&\\ 
    &&&&&&&&\\ 
    &&&&&&&&\\
    &&&&&&&&\\ 
    &&&&&&&&\\ 
    };

\draw[opacity=.5, ultra thick, red] (A-1-3.north west)-|
   (A-1-6.south east)-|
   (A-3-5.south east)-|
   (A-1-5.south west)-|cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Here one must focus on .north west\.south east which is painful for a large map...( I hoped for some concave hull alike approach