# How to color a row, column and region of a Sudoku square?

Tags: color, sudoku

I am using the `\usepackage{sudoku}` in my document (`\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{amsbook}`) and I want to color my Sudoku square like it is done for a Shidoku at the picture, but I don't know how.

[image: shidoku]

I would also like to write in a region of the Sudoku square and not only in cells, like it is done in the second picture, but I don't know how to do it either. Can anybody help me, please?

[image: sudoku]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a full MWE.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Take a look at this, select some code to produce a Sudoku square, edit your question with the code! Your question needs focus.

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/sudoku/

Comment: You can see at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86542/tikz-placing-several-numbers-in-one-cell-of-a-sudoku-grid.

Answer (score 2):

> *Note that I think I ought not answer do-it-for-mes, but sometimes do anyway.*
>
> *When I do, I answer because I want to. If my answer is of interest or use to somebody, that's a plus. If not, it is not a loss. In particular, I am less likely to be sympathetic to follow-up requests for tweaks, refinements, changes, extensions, enhancements and explanations. Moreover, explanations only make sense in response to well-formulated questions where it is clear what is required. In other cases, they are a waste of time.*

There are packages for drawing Sudoku grids of all kinds. This is not Sudoku, but you can use a generic package such as `logicpuzzle` which draws Sudoku and more.

By way of illustration, I demonstrate how to produce the first puzzle. The second is left as an exercise for the reader. In any case, one do-it-for-me is too many; two is doubly egregious. Aside from anything else, these should not both be the subject of a single question.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{logicpuzzle}
\standaloneenv{logicpuzzle}
\begin{document}
\begin{logicpuzzle}
  [
    rows=4,
    columns=4,
  ]
  \setrow{4}{{1},{2},{3},{4}}
  \setrow{3}{{3},{4},{},{}}
  \setrow{2}{{2},{},{},{}}
  \setrow{1}{{4},{},{},{}}
  \framearea{black}{\tikzpath{1}{1}{6,6,8,8,4,4,2,2}}
  \framearea{black}{\tikzpath{1}{3}{6,6,8,8,4,4,2,2}}
  \framearea{black}{\tikzpath{3}{1}{6,6,8,8,4,4,2,2}}
  \framearea{black}{\tikzpath{3}{3}{6,6,8,8,4,4,2,2}}
  \begin{puzzlebackground}
    \colorarea{orange!40}{\tikzpath{1}{3}{6,6,8,8,4,4,2,2}}
    \colorarea{blue!40}{\tikzpath{3}{4}{6,6,8,4,4,2}}
    \colorarea{green!40}{\tikzpath{1}{1}{6,8,8,4,2,2}}
  \end{puzzlebackground}
  \framepuzzle
\end{logicpuzzle}
\end{document}
```

[image: puzzle]

Comment: The south west corner is different... ;-)

Comment: @PaulGaborit Different from what?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Oh, you mean the join? I don't know why `\framepuzzle` does that. Presumably, it doesn't close the path?

Comment: Yes! It's like a bug...